# QtCreator weired bug

Tags: qt-creator

I experienced a really annoying qtcreator bug, I don't know if I get something wrong or is just a known bug and have some simple solution (I really hope so).

BUG: when I try to generate the missing members of a Q_PROPERTY using alt+Enter, the generate members are created randomly. Same bug is found when I try to generate setters and getters.

INFO: QtCreator 4.2 QT 5.7.1 MSVC 2015 32bits.

Here joined some screenshot of my qt creator
[http://imgur.com/a/8ZUjq](https://imgur.com/a/8ZUjq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what cause this bug. it's the missing public section.
You can reproduce the bug by creating a class without the public section

```
class Foo: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int c READ c WRITE setC NOTIFY cChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int d READ d WRITE setD NOTIFY dChanged)
}
```

put the cursor on the Q_PROPERTY and hit Alt+Enter and click generate missing.
When I add the public section to the class everything works as expected.
Maybe this should be corrected in the next qt-creator release, I guess it should add the public section automatically and insert the correct members.